# React ('url' )undefined properties cannot be read

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have access the state from the redux
`const { isauthenticated, user } = useSelector((state) => state.user);`

but as you can see in the code below

```
    <div className="container-fluid upnavcon">
            <span className="navbar-brand fs-1 gwen">Gadget Zone</span>
            {isauthenticated ? (
              <div className="buttonbox">
                <Link className="upnavbtns" to="/LogSign">
                  Login / Signup
                </Link>
              </div>
            ) : (
              <>
              <SpeedDial
                ariaLabel="SpeedDial tooltip example"
                onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
                onOpen={() => setOpen(true)}
                open={open}
                direction="down"
                icon={
                  <img
                    className="speedDialIcon"
                    src={`${user.avatar.url?user.avatar.url:"/logo192.png"}`}
                    alt="pic"
                    />
                }
                >
                <SpeedDialAction icon={<DashboardIcon/>} tooltipTitle="DAshboard"/>
                <SpeedDialAction icon={<DashboardIcon/>} tooltipTitle="DAshboard"/>
              </SpeedDial>
                </>
            )}
          </div>
```

that if the user isautheticated then I am showing something else
the problem is that
`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'url')` and at the very end of the error it says

```
Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
```

My state on reload is loading:false, isauthenticated:true
and after 2 secs it is loading:false, isauthenticated:true,user{...}

Comment: `user.avatar` is `undefined`

Comment: can you please change `src={user.avatar.url ? user.avatar.url:"/logo192.png"}` to `src={user.avatar?.url || "/logo192.png"}`, the try this. thanks.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I am getting the state from the redux and I get the user after I get the other states from the redux and until then I think the user is empty or undefined from loading what should i do now?

Comment: @AhmadFaraz it didn't work brother 

Comment: Please share a [mcve] for all the relevant code you are working with and have an issue using. This appears to be an issue with the way the `user` state is updated. It doesn't appear the `loading` state is used at all.

Answer (score 1):

Like Hunter McMillen added in the comments, it looks like `user.avatar` is undefined.

so when you create the ternary expression:

```
user.avatar.url ? user.avatar.url : "/logo192.png"
```

It's failing at `user.avatar.url` because `user.avatar` is undefined.

You can fix this with [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), as follows:

```
user.avatar?.url ? user.avatar.url : "/logo192.png"
```

Edit: As Ahmad Faraz said in the comments, you can further simplify this to `user.avatar?.url || "/logo192.png"`, no need to use a ternary expression.

Comment: My state on reload is loading:false, isauthenticated:true and after 2 secs it is loading:false, isauthenticated:true,user{...}

Comment: if user is undefined as well, you can just do `user?.avatar?.url || "/logo192.png"`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `user.avatar` can be undefined. To fix the error just add a check on that line:

```
src={`${user.avatar?.url ? user.avatar.url : "/logo192.png"}`}
```

Comment: it is not working in tried this actually I am getting the state from the redux and I get the user after I get the other states from the redux and until then I think the user is empty or undefined from loading what should i do because if the state will not be ready I will not be able to get the user if I add the img with the same URL and avatar it show but on reload it gives the erroir

Answer (score 0):

How are you storing your state? You could try to use ternary when you're calling it, it is not the right way to fix it but you could try this.

const { isauthenticated, user } = useSelector((state) => state?.user);